# Localization of default messages in JavaServer Faces

Tags: java, jsf

I'm trying to set up a norwegian version of a site built with JSF.
I know how to display my own messages based on what locale is set to, but I'm having trouble with the default messages (eg. when a form input is invalid). As far as I can tell, norwegian is not supported.

Does anyone know how I could overcome this?
e.g. by translating some  property file myself

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing almost the right thing, you just need to use the right property keys. The default messages.properties file is located in jsf-impl.jar (in the javax.faces package).

This contains all the messages, such as:

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.CONVERSION=Conversion error occurred.
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED=Validation Error: Value is required.
javax.faces.component.UISelectOne.INVALID=Validation Error: Value is not valid
javax.faces.component.UISelectMany.INVALID=Validation Error: Value is not valid
```

If you specify your own custom message file and use those same property keys, it will override the JSF defaults.

(See [this blog post](http://blogs.oracle.com/johnc/entry/more_jsf_validation_custom_error) for more detail)

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in detail in the [JSF specification](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/reference/api/index.html) (section 2.5.2.4 in JSF 1.2). It provides a complete list of resource keys and details the mechanisms for providing your own translations.